# Estratégia conceitual de backup de banco de dados e arquivos

Tags: banco-de-dados, sistema-de-arquivos, backup

Esta é uma pergunta conceitual que se encaixa em dois temas on-topic de [Arquitetura e engenharia de software. Conceitos e prática](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266/2884) e [pergunta de banco de dados que envolva SQL em servidor](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267/2884). Como esse tipo de pergunta tende a ser amplo demais, a abordagem sugerida e situações específicas a serem consideradas restringem a algo mais tangível.

### Abordagem sugerida

1. **A resposta é conceitual, não prática**. Pode usar uma ferramenta como exemplo para um conceito, mas o foco é o conceito.
2. **Deve-se evitar basear fortemente em opinião pessoal em detrimento de metodologias ou autores reconhecidos**. *Ok se você for um DBA com décadas de experiência*
3. Não é necessário explicar questões como aplicação ter de funcionar em alta disponibilidade, porém durante o backup a aplicação não pode parar sem justificativa. Estimativa do tempo de restauração deve ser citada
4. **Deve-se dar uma noção, ainda que vaga, da periodicidade do backup**. *De quantas em quantas horas?*
5. **Deve explicitar qual estratégia para apagar backups antigos**. Considere restauração pode ser solicitada para evento recente ou para evento de 7 ou mais dias atrás.
6. Deve sucinta, em poucos parágrafos ou uma lista de argumentos chegar a conceitos que você acredita que todo desenvolvedor deveria saber. **Imagine como explicação a um desenvolvedor novo** ou um supervisor não técnico que irá pagar seu hardware

### Situações específicas a serem consideradas

Considerar uma aplicação web típica. Possui um banco de dados SQL qualquer, e a aplicação roda em uma linguagem qualquer, que armazena arquivos de usuários em um sistema de arquivos padrão. Para evitar que a pergunta seja fechada como ampla demais, propõe-se abordar duas situações abaixo na resposta:

**Situação A**

- O banco de dados é pequeno, pode ser extraído de forma rápida, e você pode armazenar de forma ilimitada backups
- A quantidade de arquivos é pequena, pode ser compactado rapidamente, e você tem hardware para armazenar até 60x
- O hardware não é extremamente confiável: é uma máquina nova do tipo desktop ou hardware de servidor com mais de 4 anos de uso. Não há redundância por RAID.
- Pode haver falha humana

**Situação B**

- O banco de dados é enorme, e extração sem devido cuidado trava a aplicação. Você tem espaço pra no máximo 5x backups
- Quantidade de arquivos é grande, compactar no servidor de arquivos é estressante. Você tem backups para 2x~5x backups
- O hardware é extremamente confiável: redundância via hardware e máquinas com hardware específico para servidor
- Pode haver falha humana

Comment: Apesar de todos os alertas sobre "esta é uma pergunta conceitual", continua sendo o problema. Sugiro em tais perguntas embasar ao menos com Wikipedia. Exemplo: [no artigo em ingles sobre Backups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup#Objectives) é lembrada a relevância de se definir o *objetivo do backup* (RPO, RTO ou segurança). Outro ponto muito discutido é arquitetura, pois dados diferentes (ex. diferentes esquemas da base) podem possuir estratégias e objetivos diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

#### Estratégia conceitual de backup de banco de dados e arquivos

Creio que existam estratégias diferentes que sejam melhores para casos diferentes. Depende muito do contexto. Vou gostar de aprender outras estratégias aqui.

A estratégia que apresento vem sendo aplicada com sucesso na prática por mim há muitos anos, em vários casos que se encaixam na "**Situação A**" - aplicação web típica de pequena escala.

E a estratégia toda é muito simples. Vou ilustrar com as ferramentas que eu efetivamente utilizo, porém está fácil de extrair os conceitos.

Para os **arquivos de código-fonte**, uso um **sistema de controle de versão** ([Git](http://git-scm.com/)). O *site* ao vivo é um *checkout* (*working tree*) de um determinado *branch* ("*production*"). O ***deploy*** é feito através de *push* remoto em outro *branch* ("*master*") seguido de *merge* (manual ou automático através de um *hook*). Já para o ***backup***, eu tenho outro *clone* do repositório num sistema remoto, [que é mantido atualizado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150188/how-to-update-a-git-clone-mirror) através de um *update* diário, via *cronjob*.

Para os **arquivos que não são código-fonte**, por exemplo uma pasta de *uploads*, cujo conteúdo, em geral, não deve estar incluído dentro de um repositório, eu faço o ***backup*** usando uma ferramenta de sincronização de arquivos ([rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/)). Da mesma forma, o *sync* é uma tarefa diária, agendada via *cronjob*.

Finalmente, para o **banco de dados** utilizo uma ferramenta de geração de *dump* ([mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)).  Também a partir do sistema remoto existe outra tarefa diária agendada, via *cronjob*, para gerar e compactar o *dump*.

---

Assim, tenho sempre, para cada aplicação:

- um repositório espelho (com todo o código-fonte e seu histórico)
- arquivos sincronizados (espelhando o sistema em produção)
- snapshots diários do banco de dados

Tudo isso realizado sem fazer **nada** de especial no sistema em produção. Talvez uma configuração no MySQL para aceitar o acesso remoto de um endereço IP específico - enfim, alguma coisinha que precisa ajustar. O "conceito" aqui é que essa "responsabilidade" é do sistema remoto:

- os arquivos de backup estão nele
- as tarefas agendadas diárias estão nele
- o "git update", o "rsync" e o "mysqldump" rodam a partir dele, quer dizer:
- a obtenção do código-fonte, dos arquivos e do dump são "**obtidas a partir**" do sistema externo, e não "**enviadas para**" o sistema externo

---

No meu caso, de aplicações e sistemas pequenos, o intervalo de um dia para os *backups* é perfeitamente aceitável. Ainda mais considerando o que segue:

No caso do código-fonte, sempre existirá alguma(s) outra(s) cópia(s) em outro(s) lugar(es), pois afinal há o trabalho do desenvolvedor em andamento.

No caso dos arquivos de *upload*, em geral quem fez o *upload* ainda tem o arquivo no dia seguinte - ainda mais se for importante. (Detalhe: uso a opção do rsync que **não apaga** arquivos no espelho caso tenha sido removido na origem.)

No caso do banco de dados, além do *backup*, eu também deixo ativado o *log binário* - *feature* do [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) que vai registrando todas as operações (*queries*) que alteram dados, incluindo a data e hora em que foram feitas. Juntando o backup diário com o log binário, posso restaurar o banco de dados para qualquer momento exato no tempo. Eu já tive que fazer isso uma vez ("rebobinar o BD para um ponto no tempo") e fui bem-sucedido.

---

Para **apagar os backups antigos** dos bancos de dados, eu não tenho nada automatizado. Eu mesmo venho fazendo a manutenção manualmente. Mas isso não é recomendável. A estratégia melhor aqui é simplesmente automatizar esse processo também. Por exemplo: dos backups diários, manter um por mês apenas, se for anterior a 30 dias, até um máximo de 6 ou 12 meses atrás.

Já o repositório armazena todo o histórico, como qualquer repositório de código-fonte. E o espelho dos arquivos não tem histórico - é um espelho (apesar de manter arquivos deletados).

Finalmente, para o log binário do banco de dados, o MySQL oferece configurações do limite de tamanho e tempo para os mesmos. Se não oferecesse, seria o caso de configurar um *logrotate* para o mesmo.

---

Enfim, tudo depende mesmo do contexto, da escala, e das ferramentas disponíveis. A estratégia traçada acima, baseada na prática, tem como característica principal o fato de tudo ser feito a partir de fora: não cuido do "backup" no sistema que sofre o "backupeamento", mas sim no sistema externo que faz e armazena os backups. Eu tenho um VPS para isso, que cuida do backup de várias aplicações por aí. Esse VPS, por sua vez, conta com o backup oferecido pelo provedor (no caso, snapshots diários). Acho que é uma boa cobertura.

Com certeza, no caso de um banco ou uma aplicação maior ou com "dados sensíveis em alta velocidade" (tipo um eCommerce da pesada) - aí estamos em outro universo, e é necessária outra estratégia. Podemos pensar em replicação do BD,  replicações físicas em HDs palpáveis (RAID) - algo que não seja tão "nas nuvens" assim.

Comment: Boa resposta, Bruni! Se outras perguntas passarem a incluir também estratégia para _backup de código fonte com histórico_, acho que vou criar outra pergunta para abordar especificamente esse ponto. Outras questões que talvez eu faça bem elaboradas é perguntas menos conceituais e mais práticas, com citação de ferramentas e visão geral de como usar, como é o caso de Backup de MySQL que você citou. Dai o pessoal responderia lá detalhes mais técnicos. PS.:  daqui algumas horas +1 na sua resposta

Comment: Eu pensei em dar umas editadas para deixar mais de acordo com a intenção. Faltou focalizar mais a **restauração** também... no caso, a ideia de que a estratégia precisa contemplar a restauração da aplicação mesmo no caso de perda irreversível do servidor em produção: ou seja, a importância do backup estar em OUTRO local, a importância da documentação, e a experiência de realmente REFAZER a aplicação original funcionando APENAS com o backup...

Answer (score 1):

É difícil dar uma resposta conceitual porque varia muito com a implementação. Exemplos:

1. Uma estratégia para backup de bancos de dados sem perda de disponibilidade seria a replicação do seu BD no formato mestre-escravo, de modo que quando você quisesse fazer o backup você pausaria a replicação, faria o backup no *slave* e em seguida retomaria a replicação. Essa estrategia [é bem suportada no MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.6/en/replication-solutions-backups.html), mas [apresenta problemas no PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56747/5546) (por exemplo; outros SGBDs podem ter outras peculiaridades).

   - Requisito de espaço: mínimo de 3x (uma para o *master*, uma para o *slave* e uma para o backup em progresso - antes de movê-lo para armazenagem externa)
   - Periodicidade do backup: durante o tempo que a replicação está pausada, o *master* vai continuar acumulando escritas que têm de ser replicadas depois no *slave*. É a soma desses dois períodos (temo de backup, tempo de replicação) que determina o período **mínimo** entre um backup e outro.
   - Tempo de restauração: vai depender de como o backup é feito de fato (mais sobre isso adiante); o banco teria de ficar em estado somente-leitura até que a restauração seja feita.
2. Outra estratégia sem perda de disponibilidade (dessa vez específica pro PostgreSQL, mas outros podem suportar também, não é de meu conhecimento) seria o [arquivamento contínuo](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/continuous-archiving.html): usar o próprio log do SGBD (aqui chamado WAL - Write Ahead Log) tanto para a replicação (se necessário) quanto para realizar backups continuamente. Esse log grava todas as escritas feitas no banco desde o último *checkpoint*, permitindo restaurar o banco para um estado anterior arbitrário.

   - Requisito de espaço: não tenho experiência prática para comentar, mas a documentação diz que "os backups tendem a ficar bastante grandes"... Ou seja, usar essa estratégia entre um *checkpoint* e outro pode ser viável, mas esses checkpoints têm de existir de qualquer maneira. Aí, cai no problema mencionado no item acima.
   - Periodicidade do backup: o backup incremental é feito continuamente, de modo que para períodos curtos (o que é "curto" vai depender da frequência de escritas na sua aplicação específica) pode-se restaurar o banco para qualquer momento arbitrário no passado. O backup de *checkpoints*, por outro lado, sofre de restrições semelhantes ao item acima.
   - Tempo de restauração: não tenho conhecimento suficiente para estimar.

Quanto ao backup em si, a estratégia é diferente conforme a escala: bancos pequenos podem ser arquivados por uma simples operação de ***dump***, enquanto bancos maiores exigem o backup dos próprios arquivos de dados (já que a operação de *dump* é proibitivamente demorada). De novo, não tenho conhecimento suficiente para estimar o tempo de restauração em função do volume de dados, mas cabe observar que é sempre possível ter uma réplica pronta no "último estado válido" que poderia assumir rapidamente o estado de *master* no caso de uma situação "catastrófica".

### Arquivos

Tudo vai depender do formato desses arquivos e do seu propósito. Exemplos:

1. Arquivos predominantemente textuais, que formam a base do próprio site

   Nesse caso o uso de um controle de versões seria o mais apropriado, como [já apontado por @J. Bruni](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6025/215). Nesse caso, as alterações em si seriam feitas num ambiente distinto, e somente os resultados finais promovidos para o ambiente de produção. Ou seja, o backup não é feito no servidor de aplicação, mas em outro lugar.
2. Uploads de usuários, em formato textual ou binário, que não são modificados após carregados

   A estratégia que otimizaria uso de espaço nesse caso seria ter as pastas de backup refletindo a mesma estrutura da pasta do servidor [no momento do backup], e cada arquivo fazendo um link (de preferência *hardlink*) para o arquivo verdadeiro. Opcionalmente, isso pode ser precedido de uma **de-deduplicação**, de modo a conservar espaço. Dessa forma, apagar um backup antigo é uma simples questão de apagar sua pasta e tudo o que tem dentro - uma vez que o *hardlink* garante que um arquivo só será excluído de fato quando nenhuma outra pasta de backup fizer referência a ele.

   (Nota: no caso do servidor sem armazenamento confiável, pode ser interessante fazer uma cópia "real" de cada arquivo, e só a partir daí realizar os links. O [projeto boar](https://code.google.com/p/boar/) por exemplo usa essa estratégia, inclusive de de-duplicação. Além disso, ele pode ser mais viável na hora de mover arquivos para armazenamento externo - caso em que a solução por *hardlinks* apresenta problemas)
3. Arquivos binários ou texto usados e modificados pela própria aplicação

   Nesse caso, fica difícil dar uma solução genérica, exceto talvez operar no modo [*copy-on-write*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) ("copiar quando escrever") - de modo a permitir criar um *snapshot* do seu servidor sem ter que parar a aplicação. Isso é suportado no Windows por meio da funcionalidade [Shadow Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy), e no Linux por meio do sistema de arquivos [Btrfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs). Uma vez feito o *snapshot*, o backup prosseguiria conforme os itens 1 ou 2 acima, dependendo do formato dos dados.

Comment: **Resposta muito boa**. A do Bruni foi mais didática focada na Situação A, situação que a maioria aqui deve passar, enquanto a sua tendeu mais a Situação B. _Resposta mais complexa_ para um _problema mais complexo_. Em algum momento será interessante abrir questões bem detalhadas a respeito de subitens e caráter mais prático das questões de vocês aqui, como  backup com PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

Como ***analista de infraestrutura*** e não DBA vou sugerir soluções de ***backup estrutural do banco*** que em geral são utilizados em verdadeiros desastres,soluções as quais já implementei com sucesso muitas vezes, na maioria dessas soluções é necessário um processo de recuperação da base, pois mustas vezes as escritas de alguns pontos estão pela metade nessas soluções e por se tratar de backup estrutural SEMPRE é necessária uma segunda maquina

**Primeiro caso**

- sem segredo, rotinas de backup agendadas em um servidor remoto com monitoração. (Deduplicação tende a backups infinitos nesse caso)

**Segundo caso**

1. Considere um filesystem com snapshots acessíveis e/ou storages com esta função, de hora em hora um snapshot é agendado e o processo de backup realizado em outro servidor montando o snapshot como readonly, ainda haverá perda de performance por I/O, mas essa é a melhor solução para não onerar o servidor de forma continua, nem todas as bases aceitam esse tipo de solução de forma simples, mas sempre é possível scriptizar de forma segura as etapas.
2. Um segundo servidor recebendo uma copia continua dos dados com intuito apenas de backup, em bases sérias com replicação síncrona o desempenho da estrutura pode acabar sendo nivelado pelo hardware espelho e pela sincronicidade o processo de backup nesta maquina pode afetar a velocidade de escrita da maquina de produção, porem o restore dos dados pode ser feito de maneira bastante rápida e virtualmente sem perdas de dados em relação a solução anterior.
3. O mesmo que o anterior, porem com os logs enviados de forma assíncrona, há apenas um overhead de envio dos logs binários a serem replicados, quase não há interferência da maquina espelho no servidor primário, e backups podem ser feitos quase sem efeito sobre a maquina principal, porem haverão pequenas perdas no restore
4. Uma variação do anterior, porem a maquina espelho contendo um filesystem que comporte snapshot sem lock, se possível deduplicação e acesso sem restauração dos snapshots como zfs e gpfs ,filesystems dos sonhos free e pago(muito bem pago!) respectivamente, nesse caso não há necessidade da rotina de backup em si, o volume dos dados é apenas incremental, há pouco lock nestas ações que possa afetar a base de produção e o agendamento dos backups é simples. porem  a estrutura em si fica bem complexa e bastante passível de erros humanos
5. Snapshots locais sendo enviados por rede para uma maquina remota e eliminados na sequencia, só conheço o ZFS com essa capacidade, haverão perdas de dados e o trafego de rede é bastante grande, porem pode ser feito minuto a minuto, a maquina destino não precisa ter capacidade de rodar a base.

**não citei LVM para snapshot intencionalmente, tem de ser seguro, e recover de LVM é o pior dos pesadelos de um admin

Comment: sei não se tratar de uma resposta a pergunta real, mas eu realmente acho que são pontos e visões importantes que a estrutura pode fornecer como solução

Answer (score 0):

Para a situação B é necessário responder a pergunta: "Quantos dias sua aplicação poderá ficar fora do ar para a restauração de um back-up?".
Creio que o maior problema é a restauração e não a criação de um back-up.

Veja este post do Fabio Telles: "Dump não é backup!"
http://savepoint.blog.br/dump-nao-e-backup/

Comment: "dias"? Se você conta o tempo para restaurar em dias, tem algo errado ai.

Comment: @user2478690 pode por favor melhorar a pergunta? Da forma como está só vai atrair -1s. Você não só não respondeu a pergunta como apenas passou o link externo

Comment: A situação B é de um banco de dados enorme. Para um banco enorme as estratégias tradicionais de back-up e restauralção (que é o grande problema) usualmente não atendem aos requisitos de disponibilidade. Para tais tipos de banco é aconselhável a replicação, por ex. na forma mestre-escravo, e a promoção de um escravo para mestre em caso de problemas. Para um banco efetivamente grande o tempo de restauração chega a ser proibitivo em termos dos requisitos do sistema.

Comment: Acho que o @user2478690 está querendo lembrar que o conceito de "backup" nos dias de hoje (2014) é mais amplo, e que justamente RAID, replicação, etc. entram no conceito amplo. Frente de loja, aplicações bancárias, etc. tomam prejuizo com alguns segundos ou  minutos de indisponibilidade, e mais prejuizo ainda se perderem "transações em trânsito".